# Why isnt my .cpp class using my .h variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, computer-science

So I am using Visual Studio to make a simple program for intro to Object Oriented Programming. I am using C++ language to do this, in Netbeans with JAVA OPP isn't so complicated but I am having trouble here. I have to make a simple Object, I chose to make my object called Movie. I made a Movie.h and Movie.cpp file. I included .h's extensions to my Movie.cpp and main.cpp but when I create the object in my main or try to i keep getting errors and underlines because my .cpp file is not recognizing my variables declared in .h, it keeps saying the variable is undefined.

So visual studio's wants to help me out and I followed their method so in my .h files they said they will define my methods for me, meaning they will set it up for me and when I clicked it i get this format

```
    string Movie::getName()
    {
return string();
    }
```

While I am using this format for this function

```
    string getName(){
    return name;
    }
```

My variables keeps getting red underlined saying they are undefined.

My Movie.h file

```
   #pragma once

    //Header File is where all of your class defenitions will go.
    class Movie
    {
    private:
string name;
int length;
double rating;

    public:
//Constructors
//A Default constructor
Movie();

//A Constructor that takes in 3 values, an int, a double and a string
Movie(int x, double y, string z );

//Get fucntions
//Get fucntions will get the required values.
string getName();
int getLength();
double getRating();

//Set functions
//Set fucntions will set the variables to the input values.

void setName(string x);
void setLength(int y);
void setRating(double z);

//toString Function
//A toString function that will display the details of the object
void toString();

    };
```

My Movie.cpp File

```
        #include "Movie.h"
        #include "pch.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        //Default Construtor
        Movie::Movie()
        {

        }
        //A Construtor that takes in 3 values, int for length, double for rating, string for name
        Movie::Movie(int x, double y, string z)
        {

            setLength(x);
            setRating(y);
            setName(z);

        }

        //Set functions

        void setLength(int x) {
            length = x;
        }
        void setRating(double y) {
            rating = y;
        }
        void setName(string z) {
            name = z;
        }

        //Get functions
        int getLength() {
            return length;
        }
        double getRating() {
            return rating;
        }
        string getName() {
            return name;
        }
```

My .main

```
        #include "pch.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include "Movie.h"
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {

            Movie mo1();

                        mo1.setName("Inceptio");
                            mo1.setLength(123);


            cin.ignore(1);
            return 0;

        }
```

Now I havent worked on my toString method yet but I can't because I cant figure out what the real problem is, why is my .cpp not recognizing my variables? Is my format wrong? Is the visual studio's format right because I ran with their format and got bunch of errors as well or am I declaring them wrong or something? Thank you!

Comment: Add `Movie::` to all the function definitions in Movie.cpp. The way it is, those are free functions and not part of the class, hence the variables aren't recognized.

Comment: Isn't there a vexing parse?

Comment: @JVApen `Movie mo1();`? Good catch. That's an underhanding pit-fall for C++ learners. It must be `Movie mo1;`. As it is now, the compiler will read this as a function declaration instead which is surely really confusing... (I once used this for applicants interview when we were looking for C++ developers.) ;-)

Comment: Or `Movie mo1{};`

Comment: Note: there are compiler warnings for this kind of things, if you enable them, writing code becomes easier

Answer (score 0):

Main.cpp

```
//#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Movie.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Movie mo1;
  mo1.setName("Inceptio");
  mo1.setLength(123);

  cin.ignore(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Movie.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Movie_H
#define Movie_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Header File is where all of your class defenitions will go.
class Movie
{
private:
    string name;
    int length;
    double rating;

public:
    //Constructors
    //A Default constructor
    Movie();

    //A Constructor that takes in 3 values, an int, a double and a string
    Movie(int x, double y, string z);

    //Get fucntions
    //Get fucntions will get the required values.
    string getName();
    int getLength();
    double getRating();

    //Set functions
    //Set fucntions will set the variables to the input values.

    void setName(string x);
    void setLength(int y);
    void setRating(double z);

    //toString Function
    //A toString function that will display the details of the object
    void toString();
};
#endif
```

Movie.cpp

```
#include "Movie.h"
//#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Default Construtor
Movie::Movie()
{

}
//A Construtor that takes in 3 values, int for length, double for rating, string for name
Movie::Movie(int x, double y, string z)
{

    setLength(x);
    setRating(y);
    setName(z);

}

//Set functions

void Movie::setLength(int x) {
    length = x;
}
void Movie::setRating(double y) {
    rating = y;
}
void Movie::setName(string z) {
    name = z;
}

//Get functions
int Movie::getLength() {
    return length;
}
double Movie::getRating() {
    return rating;
}
string Movie::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: So I did do as you did your but I’m still getting errors, I’m kinda losing my mind because object oriented programming came to me so quickly in Java. This all makes sense but isn’t executing